# 15.10 hangs up on a jump drive

Tags: xubuntu

Ok all you linux guru's. I sure hope you guys are still watching this thread.

Here is my problem. I know, I know i have many problems....hehehe I will try to make this as short as possible. I went to linux web site and downloaded Ubuntu to a jump drive to try as per there instructions.

It didn't work. Seems something was missing or got corrupted. It took about 4.5 gigs of my monthly 5 gig alotment. grrrrrrr. So I ordered from them "Xubuntu 15.10" on a 32 gig Kingston jump drive. You are supposed to be able to plug it in and then choose "try it" or install it along with a few other selections including a help file. Well, this one does not work either ?

It goes through the boot up process to the screen that gives me the options to select "try or install" so I choose try, it starts to log on all the way through the blue Ubuntu log on screen and then goes to a black screen with a white box in the upper left corner with a bunch of DOS like commands or something. I can type in commands but nothing works. Even 'help' which they say takes me to the help page but nothing works. this is what it says in the white box......

```
[ 17.092416] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No caching page mode found
[ 17.092580] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through


BusyBox V 1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Ok, thats what is in the white box and no matter what I type in after the `(initramfs)` nothing works.

You are not supposed to have to do any of this. Just plug it in and choose "Try Ubuntu" I can't seem to find anything on the Ubuntu site to help me. I am trying to do this on an older Asus EEE PC netbook. About 6 or 7 years old. Windows 7 starter version, Intel Atom CPU N450 @ 1.66ghz, !.67GHz, 1 GB ram, 32 bit operating system.

There is nothing wrong with the computer, just slow. I know very little about Linux or typing in DOS like commands. I have even disabled Asus quick boot and this did nothing as well. I sure hope someone can help me or I just spent 30 bucks for a jump drive.. Thanks in advance.

PS, I just read on the Linux forum that my processor needs to support PAE, whatever that is ?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow            497M   63M  434M  13% /
udev            489M  4.0K  489M   1% /dev
tmpfs           199M  800K  198M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1        15G  705M   15G   5% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      677M  677M     0 100% /rofs
tmpfs           497M   16K  496M   1% /tmp
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            497M   88K  496M   1% /run/shm
```

Comment: PAE is for systems with more than 4GB of RAM you don't need it.

Comment: Neil. Thanks for the response. This is a small  asus net book, how would I unplug the hard drive? I sure am not going to take it apart everytime I want to use Linux ? My question about PAE was that somewhere on a Linux forum I read that Xubuntu needed PAE to work. So if this netbook does not have PAE are you saying that Xubuntu wont load? I bought this jump drive with Xubuntu on it so I could just plug it in and boot to it and use linux.

Comment: You need to use a different Linux OS. `Lubuntu 12.04 32-bit` or `Xubuntu 12.04 32-bit`; both of these use a non-PAE kernel by default. Can you burn Xubuntu or Lubuntu 12.04 to a Disk, or make a bootable usb drive

Comment: you want to burn this to a DVD or make a bootable flash drive from this image http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.04/release/xubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso

Comment: Ok Neil. Thanks for the help. I did what you said and now I have 12.04 up and running on my old asus net book. So just a couple of questions if you don't mind. There are five icons on the desk top. Nothing happens when I click or double click on them. I have to right click on them and then select open. And then whatever folder is in them I have to right click and select open to see what is in them. Is this right ?

Comment: Continued... It took me forever to figure out how to get my wifi card installed so I could go on line. Now that I have that taken care of when I try to download something like adobe flash player or beepme or anything else I get an error message saying to check my internet connection, well, There is nothing wrong with the connection as the web browser works just fine but is slower then windows 8.1 buy far. ???

Comment: More.... Ok, I have a new asus transformr book just like the old one I just installed xubuntu on except it is a new and has a ssd card and a 500gb hard drive and is running win. 8.1.  It takes the new asus 15 seconds to boot up win. 8.1 from dead cold. It takes the old asus 1minute and 30 sec. to boot up Linux xubuntu and this is the same  amount of time it took to boot up win. 7 starter.

Comment: Even more.....  The new asus opens firefox in just a tad over 5 seconds. The old asus running xubuntu takes a little over 8 sec. to open firefox. This a bit faster then what it used to open with windows 7 starter. Does all this sound right? Doesn't sound like I have gained much over my old windows version using linux as far as speed goes.

Comment: Still more... Oh. I figureed out how to import my bookmarks from firefox but when I shut down and then when I boot up again they are gone. Do you know how to save them on linux on my jump drive?  Sorry for all the newbee questions. Any help is welcome as I am at this point not to excited about linux but not yet quiet ready to give up yet.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. If you have new or follow-up questions, please [open a new question](/questions/ask).

Comment: Neil, what happened? I can't get into chat anymore.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I should not have said forum but question and answer site, geeeez, how would I get all this straightened out in one answer??? so where do i go to get answers??

Comment: Neil, that is what I have on a jump drive and that is what we have been trying to install on another jump drive so I have a working ubuntu that I can use from a jump drive. I thought that is what you were trying to help me with ?

Answer (score 0):

In response to trying to get my problem solved and not knowing how to use this forum or chat room it seems I can no longer post questions to Neil. Well, this really sucks. I am new to Linux and don't understand to much of it. In stead of helping me figure out what to do in this lame forum that restricts your posting size it would seem that everybody has given up on me. Well, good bye to you all and linux. This really does suck